# Before and after a transformation apply another transformation and its inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, function-and-relation-composition

So I have something like $y(x) = x\cdot5$, so whatever $x$ is, it's being scaled up by $5$.

But I could center that scaling to a different point reference other than $0$. For example $10$. So for that I end up with $y(x) = (x-10)\cdot 5+10$. I subtract $10$, making all $x$ values relative to $10$, I scale like before by multiplying by $5$, and then put things back by adding $10$. So it will look like instead of values are scaling from $0$, they are scaling from $10$.

Now, alternatively I can do this with multiplication instead of addition, so for example instead of $y(x) = \operatorname{floor}(x)$, I could increase the floor "step" size by $3$, doing $y(x) = \operatorname{floor}\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\right)\cdot3$.

And I find this kind of Give&Take or "compensation" routine to be applicable and useful with other operations.

I was just wondering if there was a proper name for this type of procedure, where you apply an operation and its inverese before and after a another operation.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a very astute observation, and yes - it shows up all over the place! This [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism) may be a bit high-brow, but it's talking about the same sort of thing you are: conjugation.

Comment: @pjs36 Many thanks for the page! It seems that is the broad view of the answers given below.  I wish I could upvote comments :)

Thank you to who edited the question. I'm not used to math stackexchange notation. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **conjugation** - specifically, the operation "before doing $A$, do $T$, and then after doing $A$, do $T^{-1}$" (more simply, "$A\mapsto T^{-1}AT$") is called **conjugation by $T$** (or conjugation by $T^{-1}$, depending on the convention!).

Comment: Thank you Noah! Someone without Mathematics backgrounds sees things like these happening and wonders about formal naming.

I'm just wondering if when you say "before doing A, to T, and then" you mean "do T" instead of "to T"?

Cheers

Comment: @probiner Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean conjugation? In group theory, 'conjugating an element $a$ by $g$' means the element $gag^{-1}$.

See [Conjugacy class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class).

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer this!